# Sufficient conditions for $f(T)$ to be compact and self adjoint whenever $T$ is compact and self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Let $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$ be bounded where $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ are the complex eigenvalues and $\{e_n\}_n$ are
an orthonormal basis of the separable space $H$. For any continuous function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ define $f(T)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(\lambda_n) \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$.

Give necessary and sufficient conditions on a continuous $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that the following holds: Whenever $T$ is compact and self adjoint, then $f(T)$ is compact and self adjoint. Note that I want to prove that the conditions are sufficient (no need to prove they are necessary).

Comment: Well, what does self-adjointness tell you about $\lambda_n$? What does compactness tell you about $\lambda_n$?

Comment: I am guessing it tells me $\lambda_n \neq 0$? It is a guess.. and I dont know how to show it.

Comment: Or is it that $\lambda_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\lambda_n> 0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Not quite. You should look up the answer to those two questions - they're both things that whoever assigned the exercise expects you to know.

Comment: In your notation, $T$ is self-adjoint and compact if and only if $\lambda_n\to 0$ and $\lambda_n\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you kindly support this with a prof? I am having trouble understanding and showing this myself.